# Sitecore document versioning

Tags: version-control, sitecore, sitecore6

This fall we will be updating numerous documents on our Sitecore 6.5 site, the content team will need to have new versions of all (or at least nearly all) documents on the site.  Rather than having the customer upload all of the new documents at once, I'm wondering if there's an easy way of creating a set of fall version documents over the next couple of months, and then be able to publish these documents at a predefined date?

Answer (score 2):

By documents I presume you mean media items... Assuming that your media items have been uploaded as versionable (i.e. created using the `/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Versioned/*` templates as opposed to using the `Unversioned` templates) then you can create a new version of the item and then set publishing restrictions for your fall date. Even if you are talking content items then the concept still applies:

[image: Publishing Restrictions]

The screenshot and [this documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/publishing/preview_and_setup/set_up_publishing_restrictions_for_an_item) is for Sitecore 8+ but the concept is the same in Sitecore 6.5 as well. You will need to set this for every document/item.

Comment: Once you have these versions, you can set their publication date and enable the auto-publisher to publish at a given date.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Quick follow up - this doesn't seem to work automatically in that you still seem to have to publish the item(s) once the start date for publishability of the item has been reached.  Is there any way to automatically publish these items?

Comment: Never mind, looks like it just took a little bit longer to update - checked it initially about 2 minutes after the start time and it hadn't, but now at about 12 minutes it's now updated...

Comment: @LeviWallach OOTB items will not publish at set time automatically unfortunately, you have to schedule it to publish (even then there are some issues around schedule timers that may mean it's not exact). Enable the [scheduled publisher in config](https://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/basics-of-sitecore-scheduled-publishing/) or use [SiteCron which will give precision](http://www.akshaysura.com/2015/06/23/sitecron-sitecore-module-for-your-everyday-scheduling-needs/) or maybe the [Sitecore Publish Module](http://www.sitecorethoughts.com/home/sitecore-scheduled-publish-module-overview).